# Is there any overhead in wrapping a function in a closure to pass it as argument

Tags: swift, performance, closures

In swift, you can pass functions as parameters to functions accepting closures. This is particularly useful to avoid syntactically polluting your code when using operators. For instance, you can write a sum as follows:

```swift
let values = 0 ..< 10
let sum = values.reduce(0, +)
```

Unfortunately, overloaded functions can lead to ambiguous situations when Swift’s inference is unable to determine the type of the expected closure from other arguments. Consider the code below for instance. The last line does not compile because Swift cannot decide what “version” of `+` I am referring to.

```
func castAndCombine<T, U>(_ pair: (Any, Any), with fn: (T, T) -> U) -> U? {
  guard let first = pair.0 as? T, let second = pair.1 as? T
    else { return nil }
  return fn(first, second)
}

// The following line cannot compile.
let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: +)
```

Unfortunately, there isn’t (or at least I am not aware of) any way to specify which `+` I mean. Nonetheless, I came up with two solutions to this problem:

1. Add a parameter to the function to disambiguate the situation:

```
func castAndCombine<T, U>(_ pair: (Any, Any), toType: T.Type, with fn: (T, T) -> U) -> U? {
  // ...
}
let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), toType: Int.self, with: +)
```

2. Leave the function’s signature unchanged and use a closure with explicit type annotations:

```
func castAndCombine<T, U>(_ pair: (Any, Any), with fn: (T, T) -> U) -> U? {
  // ...
}

let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: { (a: Int, b: Int) in a + b })
```

I personally dislike the first solution, as I feel it is not aesthetic and unnatural to use. However, I wonder if the second one adds any performance overhead, due to the creation of a closure that essentially wraps a single function, without adding any behavior.

Does anyone know if this performance overhead does actually exist and/or is significant to any extent?

Comment: Another option to resolve the ambiguity is `let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: +) as Int?` – if you *really* must define a function taking `Any` operands. (What is the actual use-case? There might be a better solution.)

Comment: `let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: (+) as (Int, Int) -> Int)` also works to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: The use case is far more complex than the code I posted here, because I tried to extract a minimal example. I am actually writing an interpreter for a language whose instructions should be matched with Swift's (to implement the language builtins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should not be any overhead if you compile with optimizations, as the compiler will most likely inline your closure.

You can verify this assumption with your first solution (as it supports both styles) by comparing the LLVM code Swift writes. LLVM is an intermediate representation used by the compiler right before creating actual machine code.

Write one file using the operator directly, i.e.:

```swift
let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), toType: Int.self, with: +)
```

Write a second file using the closure, i.e.:

```swift
let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), toType: Int.self, with: { (a: Int, b: Int) in a + b })
```

Now compile both with optimizations, asking Swift's compiler to produce the LLVM IR. Assuming your files are named `main1.swift` and `main2.swift`, you can run the following:

```sh
swift -O -emit-ir main1.swift 1>main1.ll
swift -O -emit-ir main2.swift 1>main2.ll
```

Both produced files should be identical.

```sh
diff main1.ll main2.ll
# No output
```

---

Note that the solutions suggested in the comments do not add any performance overhead either, as statically guaranteed casts do not cost any operation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `closure` to disambiguate the type, you can cast `+` to the desired type:

```
func castAndCombine<T, U>(_ pair: (Any, Any), with fn: (T, T) -> U) -> U? {
    guard let first = pair.0 as? T, let second = pair.1 as? T
        else { return nil }
    return fn(first, second)
}

// Add two Ints by concatenating them as Strings    
func +(_ lhs: Int, _ rhs: Int) -> String {
    return "\(lhs)\(rhs)"
}

if let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: (+) as (Int, Int) -> String) {
    print(x)
}
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

```
if let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: (+) as (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    print(x)
}
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Comment: Note, because I added an additional function which combines two `Int` with `+`, your solution `let x = castAndCombine((1, 2), with: { (a: Int, b: Int) in a + b })` is *still* ambiguous.

Comment: You could also add an annotation to the codomain of the closure, that is `with: { (a: Int, b: Int) -> String in a + b }`.

Comment: Sure, but that's longer than `with: (+) as (Int, Int) -> String` and the reason for the closure is just to eliminate the ambiguity.  The cast is a more head on solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't realize I could simply use casting here. It is actually more concise and I'll use that. Nonetheless, I chose @Alvae's answer because I was asking about the possible performance overhead, rather than for a solution.

Comment: @damdamo No problem. Alvae’s answer is the more direct answer to the question as asked. In general, if Swift has ambiguity issues, that means its type inference doesn’t have enough info. A cast is a good way to tell the Swift compiler your preference among the options it has.